# Simple data driven load test

Tags: jmeter, data-driven-tests

In JMeter, I need to load test an application by injecting lines from a text file into a soap message.  The goal is to see how quickly I can fire these messages at the soap web services before the system starts to tank.

I'm new to JMeter and I'm having trouble with how to put together the test case.  I'm using the While, CSV Data Set and HTTP Request elements.  But I'm struggling to make it all work.

Pseudo-code for a traditional language would look something like:

```
soap_top="some xml";
soap_end="more xml";
file=open(filename);
log=open(logfile);
while line=file.read() {
   soap_msg=soap_top + line + soap_end;
   response=send_soap(soap_msg);
   log.append(response);
}
```

I just don't know how to translate that into JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

I was over complicating the solution.  It really is this simple:
[JMeter Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkax2.png)